# Are all functions in a Banach space convergent?

Tags: convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

Are all functions in a Banach space convergent?

I need this answer in a study of wavelet analysis.

My thoughts are: since we have this definition:

Let $X$ be a Banach space. A sequence of vectors $\left \{ e_k \right \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ belonging to $X$ is a **Schauder basis** for $X$ if, for each $f \in X$, there exist unique scalar coefficients $\left \{ c_k(f) \right \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ s.t.

$f=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_k(f)e_k$.

So this equation means that the series $f=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}c_k(f)e_k$ converges with respect to the chosen order of the elements.

So since it's for each $f \in X$, can we say all functions in a Banach space are convergent?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can functions be convergent? Perhaps you are referring to the images of the functions in the Banach space...

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar, I have edited the post and added more my thoughts. Thanks

Comment: @DavideGiraudo, I have edited the post and added more my thoughts. Thanks

Comment: @Ian OK. I remove the downvote now.

Comment: any thoughts, comments?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, but not every Banach space has a Schauder base, not even every separable Banach space. So Schauder bases should be irrelevant to whatever question you have.

Comment: If $X$ has a Schauder basis, then every element of $X$ has an expansion in terms of the basis. The order of terms is important, since in general the expansion need not converge unconditionally. (For certain bases, though, the convergence is unconditional.)

Comment: Well, a normed space $X$ is a Banach space iff each absolutely convergent series in $X$ converges, so if the functions map $X\to X$, then any absolutely convergent series in $X$, and thus $f(X)$, too, converges.